# Parameter to select the chart type to be displayed on web

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I'm looking for a parameter which allows a user to select the chart type (X-Y scatter plot, bar plot, line plot etc.) from a drop down menu on a website which is interfaced with SQL Server Reporting Services.

Is there any such parameter available? If not then are there any other means to accomplish it?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2008. Is it also doable on SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty new at SSRS, but it seems that you could have a parameter which is just a droplist of hard-coded values ("bar","pie","line",etc) and then have the report actually contain all of the charts - but conditionally hide all except the chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such kind of in-build function in SSRS. But one thing you can do is create different types of chats and hide or show them depending on your parameters